# Recode missing values coded with a string in Stata

Tags: stata

I have a dataset with missing values coded "missing". How do I recode these so Stata recognizes them as missing values? When I have numeric missing values, I have been using e.g.:

```
  mvdecode _all, mv(99=. )
```

However, when I run this with a character in it, e.g.:

```
 mvdecode _all, mv("missing"=. )
```

I get the error `missing  is not a valid numlist`.

Comment: Note that "string" not "character" is really the right term here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`mvdecode` is for numeric variables **only**: the banner in the help is "Change **numeric** values to missing values" (emphasis added). So the error message should make sense: the string `"missing"` is certainly not a numeric value, so Stata stops you there. It makes no sense to say to Stata that numeric values `"missing"` should be changed to system missing, as you requested.

As for what you should do, that depends on what you mean in Stata terms by **coded** `"missing"`.

If you are referring to string variables with literal values `"missing"` which should just be replaced by the empty string `""`, then that would be a loop over all string variables:

```
  ds, has(type string)

  quietly foreach v in `r(varlist)' { 
      replace `v' = "" if `v' == "missing"
  }
```

If you are referring to numeric variables for which there is a value label `"missing"` then you need to find out the corresponding numeric value and use that in your call to `mvdecode`. Use `label list` to look up the asssociation between values and value labels.

Comment: Thanks - Just in case anyone else having similar issue as me - given data was meant to be numerical, however had been read in as strings because of the "missing" flag, I needed to add `destring, replace` after the above code to convert to numerical.

Answer (score 2):

`mvdecode` works with *numlists*, not strings (clearly stated in `help mvdecode`). The missing value for strings in Stata is denoted by `""`.

```
clear
set more off

*----- example dataset -----

sysuse auto
keep make mpg
keep in 1/5

replace make = "missing" in 2

list

*----- what you want -----

ds, has(type string)

foreach var in `r(varlist)' {
    replace `var' = "" if `var' == "missing"
}

list
list if missing(make)
```

You can verify that Stata now recognizes one missing value for the string variable using the `missing()` function.

Comment: Oh well. What we tell you twice is true.

Comment: @Nick, he might as well  believe us.